# How to specify enum field values in CORBA

Tags: corba

I want to write one enum in an idl file as -

```
module Media 
{
enum eSpeed
{
    int speed1 = 2000,
    int speed2 = 4000,
    int speed3 = 8000
};
};
```

but CORBA doesn't allow any value assignment in case of enum. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

IDL enums can't be given values. Typically what I do is remap the IDL enum to an enum of my own making in C++ (perhaps with a lookup table) that has the correct values before using it in my application code. In other words, for example, a server implementation may receive an IDL enum in a CORBA call, but then map it to an internal C++ enum with defined values via a table lookup, then pass that to the application code.

If you don't want to do that you can use constants instead of enums in your IDL:

```
const long speed1 = 2000;
const long speed2 = 4000;
```

You'll then pass `long` instead of `eSpeed` as parameters in your IDL.

Comment: No Brian, Somehow the requirement is that I have to use enums. And Is it suggested to edit the generated files from idl? Then how do I do a loook up. I would appreciate a small example!

Comment: If someone is suggesting you hand-edit the IDL to C++ or IDL to Java code then they are doing it wrong.

Comment: Create your own enum in your target language. I'm assuming your are using C++. Use this enum in your application. When you receive data over CORBA you simply translate the IDL enum into your C++ enum. One way to do this is with a lookup table. Another way is with a switch statement.